# Get index of an element using index() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  var box = $('.box');
  box.click( function() {
    console.log($(this).index());
  });
});
```

```css
div, section {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="para">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
```

In the above HTML, the last div with class `.box` is the 3rd `.box` and I want the index of the last `.box` to be `3`, but I get `4`. Which jQuery function should I used instead which will search all divs with class `box` and then return me the position of `.box` in the set on clicking the `.box`?

Comment: The index being returned is taking into consideration all the elements within the parent. If you want to filter you can either provide a selector for the method or call it against a selector. [jQuery .index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/index it's well documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.index()` when you compare it to a set of elements with `$('.box').index($(this))`

> If a selector string is passed as an argument, .index() returns an
>   integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery
>   object relative to the elements matched by the selector.

BTW, `.index()` is zero-based so the indices would be 0, 1, and 2. If you want 1, 2, and 3, just add 1 to the result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var box = $('.box');
  box.click(function() {
    console.log($('.box').index($(this)));
  });
});
```

```css
div,
section {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="para">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
```